# Where is the Unity Hub for Linux development platform download?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

I am using Lubuntu. I can't find a download link for Unity Hub on Linux. I am not referring to the Unity desktop. I want to download the Unity Hub development platform for creating 2D & 3D multiplatform experiences and games. Can someone tell me where to download it and how to set it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity Hub currently supports Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04.

To install the Unity Hub on Ubuntu, you need to add the Unity Hub Debian repository along with the public signing key to verify the integrity of the packages.

1. To add the public signing key, run the following command:

   ```
   wget -qO - https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/keys/public | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/Unity_Technologies_ApS.gpg > /dev/null
   ```
2. To add the Unity Hub repository, you need an entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Run the following command to add the Unity Hub repository:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/Unity_Technologies_ApS.gpg] https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list'
   ```
3. Update the package cache and install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install unityhub
   ```

**Note: For some systems, you may need to ensure the following:

- The directory `/usr/share/keyrings` exists.
- The user or group installing the Hub has write permissions to the `/usr/share/keyrings` directory.
- The user or group installing Unity Hub has at least read permissions to the resulting file `Unity_Technologies_ApS.gpg`.

To remove the Unity Hub from the system, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove unityhub
```

<sub>source: [Install the Unity Hub | Unity Hub | 3.0](https://docs.unity3d.com/hub/manual/InstallHub.html#install-hub-linux)</sub>

Comment: Ok so I actualy just downloaded Ubuntu and dumped Lubuntu. And Thanks

Comment: @Ryanozolins If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.